# how to find duplicate array values in perl

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the most efficient way to check for duplicates in an array of data using Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011888/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-check-for-duplicates-in-an-array-of-data-using)

How to find duplicate values in array?

This is my array:

```
@arr - ("one","two","one","three","two");
```

Output will be:

```
one
two
```

Code:

```
while (<RFH>) {
    chomp;
    @arr = split(/\|/,$_);
    push(@arr1,$arr[4]."\n");
}
```

Comment: Why is "three" not supposed to be in the output?

Answer (score 8):

One pass solution:

```
my %seen = ();
@dup = map { 1==$seen{$_}++ ? $_ : () } @list;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 my %cnt;
 $cnt{$_}++ for @arr;
 print "$_\n" for grep $cnt{$_} > 1, keys %cnt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way using a Hash:

```
my @arr = ("one", "two", "one", "three", "two");
my %arr_counts;
for (@arr) { $arr_counts{$_}++ };
my @dupes = grep { $arr_counts{$_} > 1 } keys %arr_counts;
```

Note that a Hash does not maintain sort order. It isn't random so if you run with the same list you'll get the same result but the order will change in practice.