# In Perl, how can I find duplicate values in an array without using a hash?

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the most efficient way to check for duplicates in an array of data using Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011888/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-check-for-duplicates-in-an-array-of-data-using)

what is the best way to find the duplicate values in array without using hash ,

```
@A = ("foo","baz","bar","foo","baz","foo");
```

This is my array, how to pull only duplicate values, like:

```
foo
baz
```

```
@arr1 = (
          '2017554310',
          '2078991086',
          '2163824970',
          '2405206346',
          '2769562630',
          '2769562630',
          '3137026006',
          '3232651356',
          '3369962470',
          '3865302266',
          '4107452620',
          '4232926280',
          '5205689000',
          '5613613000',
          '6105668446',
          '6187592436',
          '6239350730',
          '6239350730',
          '7024698706',
          '7024698706',
          '7024698706',
          '7024698706',
          '7047088496',
          '7136929460',
          '7149705670',
          '7178455806',
          '7607491726',
          '7757710940',
          '8056423386',
          '8325522340',
          '8325522340',
          '8437352856',
          '8437352856',
          '8437352856',
          '9738570770'
        );
```

Comment: Is this homework? Why wouldn't you want to use a hash?

Comment: Refer this for more info: **[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011888/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-check-for-duplicates-in-an-array-of-data-using][1]**


[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011888/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-check-for-duplicates-in-an-array-of-data-using

Comment: This Answer seems most related to you but you may need to modify little bit.  **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011888/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-check-for-duplicates-in-an-array-of-data-using/3012159#3012159**

Comment: Yes, but this is akin to make a wheeled cart without using any wheels. It can be done but, why?

Comment: BTW, this is very easily done but I fail to see the point. Any answer will be the wrong way to accomplish this task, unless this is some form of homework.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera : Or a sandwich without bread :)

Comment: How is this a duplicate? All the _efficient_ ways of finding duplicates in an array in Perl involve a hash (or `sort`), but if you don't care about efficiency, `for my $i (1 .. $#A) { print $A[$i] if 1 == grep $_ eq $A[$i], @A[0 .. $i-1]; }` should do the job just fine.

Comment: How about character efficiency?: `map{$t=$_;push@{(grep{$t eq$_}@u)?\@d:\@u},$t}@ARGV;print"$_\n"for@d`

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why you have the *no hash* restriction, or no external modules. What if it's one of the standard Perl modules like `File::Basename` or `File::Find`? These come with the standard Perl install.

Can you sort your array?

```
my @A = qw(foo baz bar foo baz foo);
my @B = sort @A;
```

Now `@B` is equal to `qw*bar baz baz foo foo foo)`. You can then go through this array and see if the previous value equals the last value:

```
my @B = sort @A;
my $previous = pop @B;    #Just to start out:

foreach my $value (@B) {
   if ($previous eq $value) {  #Assuming strings only cause I can't use Scalar::Utils
      print qq("$value" is a duplicate!\n);
   }
   $previous = $value;
}
```

This will print out multiple instances of `"foo" is a duplicate` (one for each duplicate). If you don't want that, you'll have to test to see whether or not you've previously printed out that statement.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly buggy and very likely pointless:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my @A = ("foo","baz","bar","foo","baz","foo");
@A = sort @A;

my @duplicates;
my $prev = pop @A;

while (defined(my $x = pop @A)) {
    if ($prev eq $x) {
        push @duplicates, $x;
        while (defined(my $y = pop @A)) {
            if ($y ne $x) {
                $prev = $y;
                last;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $prev = $x;
    }
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@duplicates;
```

Comment: thx, but this am not sure why this snippet not worked for this number array, when i print dummper, it is just printing the empty array, check my update, i added the new array

Comment: I had forgotten about the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'List::MoreUtils'

```
perl -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -e '@A=("foo","baz","bar"","foo");print join " ", uniq(@A),"\n"'     
foo baz bar
```

Comment: `uniq` uses a hash, so this doesn't fulfil the requires of the question.

Comment: The question is asking for non-unique elements.

Comment: @Quentin: Fair enough, but I can't see why the OP would care.

Comment: @Zaid: Oops. I totally misread the question.  My apologies.

Comment: @James_R_Ferguson — Presumably because it is a non-real-world situation.

Comment: @Quentin: And in the abstract is fair enough reason, though I missed that inference and took the question to be relative to his/her own code :-)