# Finding out duplicate names from an xml file

Tags: perl, perlscript

I have an xml file from which I have to find the duplicates.

My XML file looks like this

[image: Reference XML]

I want to find the count of all element names

I tried the following code to first take all the names into a text file:

[image: Script I have wrote till now]

But this throws an error saying `Can't find LibXML`.

Comment: you can directly write your code in the question.

Comment: Looks linke you have to install a nativ library called libXML. Which OS do you use?

Comment: you can take all the element in an array and then follow : **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011888/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-check-for-duplicates-in-an-array-of-data-using** link

Comment: Instead of adding image for reference, write your code and XML fine in the question. It would be helpful for people who want help you.

Comment: where is the title element in you sample file sorry image?

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot of your code. Just post your code. Ideally self contained as an [mcve]

Comment: Please read and become familiar with Stack Overflow, and what sort of questions are acceptable. You should also read [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Images are occasionally useful, for instance to show the layout of a graphical display, but in general data and code should be posted as *text* so that we can copy it to experiment and reproduce the problem ourselves

Comment: I don't think the error is `Can't find LibXML`. Please post the *full error message*. It will include a source file path and a line number.

Comment: Is this homework? Counting the occurrences of element names isn't generally a useful thing to do. You are welcome to ask about homework problems, but the nature of the answers should change to help you to learn

Comment: is there any way to do this without using a libXML parser ?

Comment: @sureshbalaji it's a bad idea to avoid using a proper parser. What issues do you have with the answer I gave below?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install the `XML::LibXML` module

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the module [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML), from the command line:

```
cpan XML::LibXML
```

Before doing so you need the non perl dependancies this module requires detailed in the [README](https://metacpan.org/source/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0126/README):

> Prior to installation you MUST have installed the libxml2 library. You
>   can get the latest libxml2 version from....